# C++ class member: Why does class member return different value from second access?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm new to C++, and wrote NumberStack class in stack.cpp as follows, but the result is different from what I expected, So I need your help:

```
#include <iostream>

class LinkedListNode {
    public:
        int value;
        LinkedListNode* next;

        LinkedListNode(int initialValue) {
            value = initialValue;
        }
};

class NumberStack {
    public:
        LinkedListNode* head;

        NumberStack(int initialValue) {
            LinkedListNode node(initialValue);
            node.next = NULL;
            head = &node;
        }

        void push(int initialValue) {
            LinkedListNode node(initialValue);
            node.next = head;
            head = &node;
        }

        int top() {
            return head->value;
        }
    private:
};

int main() {
    NumberStack myStack(6);
    myStack.push(2);
    myStack.push(5);

    std::cout << myStack.top() << "\n";
    std::cout << myStack.top() << "\n";
    std::cout << myStack.top() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

When executing this file, I got output like this:

```
$ g++ stack.cpp
$ ./a.out
5
45264732
45264732
```

I expected output would be like this.

```
5
5
5
```

So what caused this?
I'm using MacOS Big Sur

Comment: `head = &node;` - You are saving off a pointer to a temporary stack variable, which immediately is destroyed when `node` goes out of scope.  Any subsequent attempts to read from `head` invoke Undefined Behavior.  You probably want to allocate your `LinkedListNode`s on the heap so they outlive their local stack frame.

Comment: You get different values because your stack stores addresses of local variables, and uses these addresses after the local variable goes out of scope.

Comment: Side note: If I'm remembering correctly, Herb Sutter uses a linked list in [this presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE) to demonstrate the use of smart pointers. If I'm wrong, this is the one with trees and it's not that different. With a smart pointer you get the benefits of dynamic allocation without losing much of the simpler memory management of an automatic allocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three changes that you need to make:

- Initialize node's `next' in the constructor
- Initialize `head` to `nullptr`
- Allocate nodes dynamically

Here is how:

```
LinkedListNode(int v, LinkedListNode* n = nullptr): value(v), next(n) {}
```

Then call

```
head = new LinkedListNode(initialValue, head);
```

I would also give `NumberStack` a default constructor, rather than a constructor that takes the initial value.

Comment: Thanks I managed to fix the problem with your suggestion! And thanks to other guys for explaining reasons

Comment: "*Allocate nodes dynamically*" - which then requires a 4th change - implement support for the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), by adding copy/move constructors, copy/move assignment operators, and a destructor.